# Can you run a version 3 .Net binary on a version 2 CLR install?

Tags: .net, clr

We're considering writing the next version of out project in using .Net 3, but are wondering if we can take the hit on forcing end users to install the .net framework version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure you are only using .NET 2.0 compatible functionality then you should only use .NET 2.0 assemblies. Then you know your safe and sound.

Answer (score 1):

[This article from Jean-Baptiste Evain](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2008/09/14/c-3-and-linq-on-net-2) explains how you can use C# 3.0 and LINQ and targeting machines on which there is only .NET 2.0 runtime installed.

The idea is to use System.Core [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) implementation, which is licensed under the MIT/X11 license.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3.0 is a bad name for some new libraries: WPF, WCF, Workflow and InfoCard. The CLR is still version 2.0, ASP.NET is still version 2.0, and Windows Forms is still version 2.0.

In development, .NET 3.0 was called WinFX.